# Prestashop nested link to product in top horizontal menu

Tags: navigation, prestashop

I have this problem:

I am using Top Horizontal Menu as a top navigation in Prestashop, and I need certain categories to have PRODUCTS instead of subcategories to be displayed as a second navigation level.

Ive managed to add these products in the Top Hor Menu settings, but they can be only in top level there.

Is there a way to do that, and be able to setup, which products and where to display manually?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to nest products in the default menu module that ships with Prestashop 1.6 (nor with lower versions).

It is neither possible to override a module's behaviour without editing the module itself so you will have to either edit the blocktopmenu.php file or duplicate the module and customize the behaviour in your new module (changing module name, classes, etc).

You might want to have a look at the file `blocktopmenu.php`, specifically, method `generateCategoriesMenu`.

Bear in mind that if you edit the module directly, you will loose any changes you make when you update it.